# IF-statement depending on notebook.page.label (gtk#)

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I am realtively new to C# and am trying to have an action in my toolbar that will act depending on which page in a notebook that I am currently "viewing".

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
protected void OnRefreshActionActivated (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (mynotebook.CurrentPage.Equals == pgMyNotebookPage) 
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "You are viewing the first page";
    } 
    else 
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "You are viewing the second page";
    }

}
```

However I can't seem to get this to work. Any pointers?

Regards,

Christian

Comment: what is the `type` of CurrentPage? is it string or object

Comment: It is a page in a Notebook (which is a widget), not sure what you mean by type in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a messagedialog that showed me the output of mynotebook.CurrentPage. It turned out that each page was assigned a number starting with 0.

This is the working code:

```
protected void OnRefreshActionActivated (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (nbMain.CurrentPage == 0)
    {
            lblMsg.Text = "You are viewing the first page.";

    }
    else
    { 
           lblMsg.Text = "You are viewing the first page.";

    }
```

}